# How to prove that there will always exists such a polynomial?(solution verification)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

This question is from my algebraic geometry assignment and I am struck on it.

> Show that given any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 1$ there always exists a polynomial $f(X_1,...,X_n)\in K[X_1,...,X_n]$, K is not algebraically closed field such that $V_K(f)=${(0,...,0)}.

Here, $V_K(f) $ ={$x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in K^n | f(x_1,...,x_n)=0$}.

For $K=\mathbb{Q} $ and $K=\mathbb{R}$, f can be taken as ${X_1}^2 +...+ {X_n}^2$ . I think same f will work for any K. Am I right?

Comment: The phrasing seems odd.  Are you assured that $K$ is not algebraically closed?  Any other information? But your example fails over $\mathbb Q[i]$, say.

Comment: @lulu Ya , in the question K is given to be not algebraically closed.

Comment: So, then you'll have to use the fact that you can find some polynomial without any roots over $K$.

Comment: @lulu So, my polynomial can't be generalized over K?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "generalize".  The polynomial you wrote down has many roots over $\mathbb Q[i]$, for example.

Comment: @lulu Ya I got it